# Как сделать запись контейнера map в файл?

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть задание разработать что то типо регистрации студента. Для этой цели я выбрал контейнер map, который содержит ключ(пароль) и содержит объект класса Student. Где вся информация о студенте соответственно. Как сохранить эту хэштаблицу в файл и как записать информацию из файла?

Comment: Поэлементно. С учетом того, что не-POD писать просто через `write` нельзя.

Comment: Можно использовать `boost::serialization`.